# Are there sterilisation methods that do not denature proteins as heat does?

Tags: proteins, sterilisation

Context:
Most countries require milk to be sterilised through radiation or heat to remove possible harmful bacteria. Both of these processes denature the proteins in the milk ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denaturation_%28biochemistry%29)).

Are there methods of sterilisation that will not denature proteins?

Comment: does radiation denature protein?

Comment: Why would a denatured protein in milk cause problems in the human body? Could you provide source / example for this?

Comment: About what problems in the human body are you talking? Please provide a source for this claim.

Comment: Read about pasteurization. Plus denaturing the native proteins won't cause any problem unless of course it coagulates to form an insoluble mass; in any case it is going to be digested in the stomach

Comment: I'd recommend removing the claim about human health as it's very questionable. Sterilisation by heat can, depending on the actual temperature, indeed denature proteins. Similarly, strong radiation will ultimately break molecules. I can't tell you whether the levels used to sterilise milk are sufficient to denature anything contained in it though. In general of course, "Are there sterilisation methods that do not denature proteins as heat does?" should be a valid question.

Comment: Filtration through a 0.45 micron filter is how we used to routinely sterilize laboratory solutions that we could not sterilize in the autoclave (or if we were in a hurry). This works primarily based on molecular size, so, for example, the viruses, bacteria, and fungi that are larger than the pores  will be retained on the filter, and everything else in the solution will pass through. There are filters available with different sized pores. I have never tried this with a colloid like milk. It seems like this Question was placed "On Hold" so I don't think I could "Answer" it, hence a comment.

Comment: Most countries require *pasteurization* and not sterilization of milk (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasteurization), but that also involves heat. It doesn't result in denaturation of the proteins however - who would drink curdled milk?